# Negating variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make a switch for discord.js, where a mentioned role gets removed when the user already has it, and if he doesn´t have it, it gets attached. So the code here is

```
let tempRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", args);

            if(message.member.roles.has(tempRole)) {
            console.log(`User has the role`);
        }
```

args is the array for the command params, like "!role [role name with spaces]"
So if I have the role "Test", and I type "!role Test" it outputs "User has the role"
so how is the code for the opposite, if the user doesn´t have the role?
Because

```
else if(message.member.roles.has(!tempRole)) {
            console.log(`User has not the role`);
        }
```

isn´t really working, but the '!' is the only thing i know to negate the result

Comment: ... `if (!message.member.roles.has(tempRole))` Negating whatever `tempRole` contains seems backward--that's not the condition, it's an expression *used* in the condition. You *say* you want to "negate the result", but that's not what you're doing.

Comment: Also if you already have a block for the positive result, you don't need a second check, just use `else`

Comment: Basically, same reason you write `!role "Test"` instead of `role !Test` applies to JS as well.

Answer (score 2):

The `!` operator negates whatever is found on the right side, in your case you are only negating the `tempRole`, however what you really want is to negate the result of the `has` call, like this:

```
!message.member.roles.has(tempRole)
```

Nonetheless since there is already an `if` statement verifying if the user has the role you could just use `else`

```
let tempRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", args);

if(message.member.roles.has(tempRole)) {
  console.log(`User has the role`);
} else {
  console.log(`User has not the role`);
}
```

Or even shorter with the ternary operator

```
message.member.roler.has(tempRole) 
  ? console.log('User has the role')
  : console.log(`User has not the role`);
```